# Java - ArrayList returns only one value from the database

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to make an API that will response all the data from the database in a json format. I already succeeded in creating this API and manage to fetch some data from it. What my concern is that the data returns only the last row from the database when i'm calling the API.

when i'm logging the **plancode** before adding it inside the listobj, the plancode returns all the data from the database. But whenever i return the **listobj** it only returns the last row from the db. Thank you for your help!

Here's the code i used.

```
        public ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> PlanCodesdb(String dbip,int dbport, String dbname, String dbuser,String dbpwd) throws SQLException, JSONException{
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        String procname = "PlanCodes";
        String loggerLabel = procname + "-" +  dbip + "-" + dbname;

        str.append("SELECT brand, product_type, load_package, keyword, denomination, list_price AS wallet_cost, validity FROM plan_code_tbl");
        com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource ds = new com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource();

        ds.setServerName(dbip);
        ds.setPortNumber(dbport);
        ds.setDatabaseName(dbname);
        ds.setUser(dbuser);
        ds.setPassword(dbpwd);
        conn = ds.getConnection();
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(str.toString());
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> listobj = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
        rs = ps.getResultSet();
        ResultSetMetaData metadata =  rs.getMetaData();
        ArrayList<String> key = new ArrayList<String>();
        // System.out.println("column counts: "+metadata.getColumnCount());
        logger.info("COlumn counts: " + metadata.getColumnCount());
        for (int i=1; i <= metadata.getColumnCount(); i ++){
            String columname = metadata.getColumnLabel(i);
//          logger.info(loggerLabel + "plancode columnname = " + columname); 
            //  System.out.println("key:"+columname);
            key.add(columname);
        }
        HashMap<String,Object> plancodes = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        while(rs.next()){
            for (String columname : key){                                           
                try{
                    String colVal = rs.getString(columname);
//                      logger.info("columname: "+columname+" colVal:"+colVal);
                    plancodes.put(columname, colVal);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    logger.info(loggerLabel + "Error Exception: "+e);
                }
            }
            listobj.add(plancodes);
//          logger.info("plan code response..."); 
            // logger.info("brand: "+bean.getBrand()+ "\n product_type: "+ bean.getProductType() + "\n load_package: "+ bean.getLoadPackage() +"\n keyword: "+bean.getKeyword()+"\n denomination: "+bean.getDenomination()+"\n list_price: "+bean.getListPrice()+"\n retailer discount: "+bean.getRetailerDiscount()+"\n validity: "+bean.getValidity());        
        }
        return listobj;
    }
```

Comment: Please write out your code in the question rather than sending a link to a screenshot.

Comment: i think its due to HashMap,if columnname has the same name as the previous value, it will overide the key

Comment: Sorry, the question is now edited

Comment: I would imagine that you would want to `clear` or `redecalre` `plancodes` for each iteration of your `while` loop

Comment: @Eliethesaiyan, when i'm trying to print the number of data from plancodes it shows all the data from the database. but when i'm returning the listobj it only displays the last value of the array. I think they don't have duplicate entries in the db

Comment: can you try by printing the `columname` and see what you get?

Comment: logger.info(loggerLabel + "Error Exception: "+e);
                }
            }
        
//          logger.info("plan code response...");   } listobj.add(plancodes); listobj.add should be inside that brackets, after string columnname : key loop is over, not outside

Comment: @Extreme my column counts returns 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HashMap<String,Object> plancodes = new HashMap<String,Object>();
while(rs.next()){
    for (String columname : key){                                           
        try{
            String colVal = rs.getString(columname);
            // logger.info("columname: "+columname+" colVal:"+colVal);
            plancodes.put(columname, colVal);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.info(loggerLabel + "Error Exception: "+e);
        }
    }
    listobj.add(plancodes);
    // logger.info("plan code response..."); 
    // logger.info("brand: "+bean.getBrand()+ "\n product_type: "+ bean.getProductType() + "\n load_package: "+ bean.getLoadPackage() +"\n keyword: "+bean.getKeyword()+"\n denomination: "+bean.getDenomination()+"\n list_price: "+bean.getListPrice()+"\n retailer discount: "+bean.getRetailerDiscount()+"\n validity: "+bean.getValidity());        
}
```

The problem is that you keep updating the same `Map` and adding it to the list. You need to create the `Map` *inside* the `while` loop:

```
while(rs.next()){
    HashMap<String,Object> plancodes = new HashMap<String,Object>();
```

so that every element of the list is a new `Map`.

Comment: Thank you so much moving hashmap element solves my problem

Answer (score 0):

You are using Map Key as a 'String' and in your map, key is 'columname'. Column names will be same for all the rows. So on each iteration your map will replace existing key with the next key i.e columnname and value. Thats why you are getting only one row in the list. 
So don't use string as map key. Use some UNIQUE VALUE TO AVOID SUCH ISSUES.
Example:

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
map.put("abc","1");`enter code here`
map.put("cde","2");
map.put("abc","3")
```

In map result you will find only two records i.e cde 2 and abc **3**. Because when you add same string key abc twice. It will get replaced by the latest one.
Hope it answers your question. Good luck!

Comment: I'm sorry I'm just new to java. how can I put a unique value when i'm trying to add a data from the database as you see from my code. Thank you

Comment: You can make change as per the other answer...That solution will work....just create new map inside a while loop so that for every record you will have a new Map object with different data. And later you can add that Map to a list.